# Accessing localhost outside of server

Tags: apache, sockets

I am new to node.js and am trying to get into the hang of actually using it. I am very familiar with JavaScript so the language itself is self-explanatory but the use of Node.js is quite different from the browser implementation.

I have my own remote virtual server and have installed Node and the Package Manager and everything works as expected. I am not exactly a server extraordinaire and have limited experience with the Terminal and Apache Configurations.

I can run my server using:

```
nodejs index.js
```

Which gives me: `listening on *:3300` as expected.

I can then access my localhost from the terminal using: `curl http://localhost:3300/` which gives me the response I expect.

Given that the website that links to my server is `https://example.com`, how do I allow this link to access: `http://localhost:3300/` so that I can actually use my node server in production? For example, `http://localhost:3300/` runs a Socket Server that I would like to use using Socket.io on `https://example.com/chat.html` with the JavaScript:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3300/', {transports: ['websocket'], upgrade: false});
```

Comment: This is not at all related to Node.js. You just have to expose the ports.

Comment: @NiklasHigi Well, I guess I would not be asking this question if I knew how to `just expose the ports` now would I? I asked because I want to learn, not to be told very vaguely how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, this question has nothing to do with `nodeJS`.

localhost is a hostname that means **this** computer. it's equivalent to  `127.0.0.1` or whatever IP address you can refer to your computer.
After the double colon (`:`) you enter the port number.

So if you want to make an HTTP call to a web-server running on your server, you have to know what is the IP address of your server, or the domain name, and then you call it with the port number where the server is running.

For Instance, you would call `https://example.com:3300/chat.html` to make an HTTP call to a server running on `example.com` with port 3300.

Keep in mind, that you have to make sure with your firewall configuration, that the specific port is open for incoming HTTP requests.

Comment: I thought it would be as simple as doing `https://example.com:3300` but this fails to do anything but cause a `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`.

Comment: If you try to do `https://example.com:3300` from your terminal do you also get the error?

Comment: It is most probably a firewall issue

Comment: `sudo ufw status` => `Status: inactive`

Comment: I'm not a Network expert, But it might also be configurable in your hosting settings. we can determine it if you will answer my previous question. What happens when you try to access from your server.

Comment: It was to do with my host provider

Comment: Thanks for the update. I guess it was a firewall configuration in your Host provider's end, was it?

Comment: Yeah it was. I have a virtual dedicated server with 1and1 hosting and in their cloud configurations I have to open specific Ports

Comment: Yep, I figured so